# How effective will a window unit AC be for a garage?

Tags: air-conditioning, garage

We have a 3-car tandem garage on our house in Texas. This summer, we're planning on having a family reunion and were thinking of using the 3rd bay as an overflow area for the people who couldn't fit inside.

Given that it will easily be in the 90's during any given summer day, and the garage isn't insulated, what do you think can be reasonably expected by throwing in my backup window unit?  I'm definitely not expecting to freeze anyone out, but I also would hope that it could keep the garage from being unbearable.

Just wondering if anyone has tried this, and what your experience has been.  TIA.

Answer (score 2):

It's all math.

You need 1 ton (12,000 btus) of cooling per 400 square feet.

You need about 500-600 btus of cooling per person.

So in 400 square feet you can expect to cool up to 20 people per ton assuming they aren't actively exercising. I wouldn't do any more than 10 people per ton if you want them to feel at least a little chill.

A hot and uninsulated garage will likely need 20% more btus than my calculations above.

You should turn these units on 6-8 hours before guests arrive to ensure your garage is sufficiently comfortable.

Comment: i.e., OP will probably need to beg/buy/borrow/rent a couple of additional AC units an have them pre-cool the garage for a day or so _before_ the event if he wants people to not melt in the garage, right? Rental of a couple of portable units is probably the way to go.

Comment: @FreeMan The general consensus is that portable units are not worth their price tag. 2-3 window units at 10-16k btus each would probably suffice.